# Нужно сделать остановку анимации с помощью click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>move</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1 id="heading">Привет, мир!</h1>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
 <script>



var leftOffset = 0;
var topOffset = 0;
var dir = "right";

var moveHeading = function () {$("#heading").offset({ left: leftOffset,                        top: topOffset})
if(dir == "right")    
leftOffset++;
else
leftOffset--;
if(leftOffset < 0 && topOffset > 0)
{
 leftOffset = 0;
 topOffset--;
}
else if(topOffset == 0)
{
 dir = "right";
}
if (leftOffset > 200) {
leftOffset = 200;

topOffset++;
if (topOffset > 200) {
 topOffset =200;
 dir = "left";
 }
 else if(topOffset < 0)
 {
 topOffset =0;
 }
 } 
 };


 setInterval(moveHeading, 30)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

удалите интервал по клику

```js
var leftOffset = 0;
var topOffset = 0;
var dir = "right";

var moveHeading = function() {
  $("#heading").offset({
    left: leftOffset,
    top: topOffset
  })
  if (dir == "right")
    leftOffset++;
  else
    leftOffset--;
  if (leftOffset < 0 && topOffset > 0) {
    leftOffset = 0;
    topOffset--;
  } else if (topOffset == 0) {
    dir = "right";
  }
  if (leftOffset > 200) {
    leftOffset = 200;

    topOffset++;
    if (topOffset > 200) {
      topOffset = 200;
      dir = "left";
    } else if (topOffset < 0) {
      topOffset = 0;
    }
  }
};


var intervalId = setInterval(moveHeading, 30);

$("#heading").on('click', function () {
  clearInterval(intervalId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="heading">Привет, мир!</h1>
```